# Recover camera Pose from animation Path

Tags: animation, camera, bezier-curves

I have a camera object, let's say Cam1, following a path defined by a BezierCurve. The bezierCurve is defined as a constraint for the camera, and the camera follows it over 240 frames in an animation.

I would like to know if there is a way to recover the poses (rotation and position) of the camera for each frame.

I already tried some solution on python scripts, but each times it appears that my camera pose remains constant. Does anyone know if there is a practical way to do it?

Thank you in advance.